# Prove kernel of f(g(x)) is the inverse transformation g of kernel of f.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Basically, I'm trying to prove the following statement. However, I never try this before, and not sure if I missing any or the idea is completely wrong.

For linear transformation $f: V \to W$, and $g: U \to V$

To prove the statement $\ker(f(g(x))=g^{-1}(\ker(f(x))$ is True.

For the L.H.S, I get
$$
\ker(f \circ g) = \{ x\in U \mid f(g(x))=0\}
$$

For the R.H.S, I get
$$
\ker(f)=\{ y \in V \mid f(y)=0 \}
$$
Since $g^{-1}(v)=\{ z \in U \mid g(z)=v, $ where $v\in V \}$, I'm thinking to substitue the $v$ in $g^{-1}$ to the kernel of f. Then I could show $g^{-1}(\ker(f))=\{ z\in U \mid f(g(z))=0 \}$.

Finally, the two sets are the same. So the statement is True. I believe I missed something in the mid, but not sure how to connect them together. Or my direction is wrong.

Comment: Try to do it element wise. Say start with $v \in \mathrm{ker}(f(g(x))$ and show that $v \in g^{-1}(\mathrm{ker}(f(x)))$ and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not do any substitutions or other such stuff. Just write out what the inverse image is and remember what being in the kernel means. Then you get something similar to the following.

If $u\in\ker(f\circ g)$, then $f(g(u))=0$, so $g(u)\in\ker(f)$. This, however, is the same thing as $u\in g^{-1}(\ker(f)) = \{ u\in U\ |\ g(u)\in\ker(f)\}$. Conversely, if $u\in g^{-1}(\ker(f))$, then $f(g(u))=0$ and $u\in\ker(f\circ g)$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.